# Cython + external c++ lib

Tags: python, c++, cython, v8

I try run v8 (google javascript engine) in python. Try do this like this example https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started:

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import os
from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_vars

(opt,) = get_config_vars('OPT')
os.environ['OPT'] = " ".join(
    flag for flag in opt.split() if flag != '-Wstrict-prototypes'
)

setup(
    name = 'helloworld',
    ext_modules = cythonize(
        Extension(
            "helloworld",
            ["helloworld.pyx"],
            language = "c++",
            libraries = ["v8"],
            library_dirs = ["v8"],
            include_dirs = ["v8/include"],
            extra_compile_args = ["-std=c++11"],
            extra_link_args = ["-std=c++11"],
            cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}
        )
    )
)
```

helloworld.pyx

```
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "v8.h":
        cdef bool c_initx "v8::V8::InitializeICU"()

cdef class Script:
        def test(self):
                c_initx()

                return "wow"
```

Compilation process is OK but i can't import helloworld:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import helloworld
ImportError: /opt/cython/helloworld.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2v82V813InitializeICUEPKc
```

I use latest v8 version from github https://github.com/v8/v8

Comment: The "getting started" page you've linked to lists a whole long list of libraries to link against (step 3 of "run the example"). Is that your problem?